# Coodinates Not Showing on Map in R

Tags: r, rstudio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKMVC.jpg)
I am making maps to display the nesting sites of storks.

I have successfully made 3 of the 4 maps that I need. They all use the same type of data but just use different years (2016-2019).

For some reason when I code for the 4th map, no data points come up, the map is totally blank (Please see screen shot below).

I have tried remaking the Excel.csv file that the data comes from, I have tried reopening R, and I have tried turning my fill colours off on my map.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why it may not be working? I am most confused as the code worked perfectly for the last 3 maps!

Here is a sample of my code:

```
portugal_map<-ggplot(data=world)+geom_sf(color='black',fill='darkolivegreen1')+
  xlab('Longitude')+ylab('Latitude')+ggtitle('South Portugal',subtitle = ('Stork Nests 2019'))+
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-10.167179, -7.355167), ylim = c(36.897690, 39.004960), expand = FALSE)

portugal_map

portugal_nests_fourth<-portugal_map +
  geom_point(data=X2019_Stork_Data,aes(x=Longitude,y=Latitude,fill=Nest),shape=21,size=2,color="black")

portugal_nests_fourth
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show a sample of `X2019_Stork_Data`? It may be that the coordinates are outside of the limits you set in `coord_sf`.

Comment: I have added a screenshot, hope it helps!

Comment: did you get any warning text when the plot was completed? like Conor said, it might be a case that all of your nest locations are outside of the coordinates of the map.

Comment: No I haven't had any warnings come up for it, it processes it as if it's a perfectly fine piece of code, almost as if it's ignored the fact that it should be plotting points.